Azure openAI on NodeJS with token instead of API-key credentials
I am trying to get the @azure/openai nodejs package to work with a token received from an OAuth2 (clientId, clientSecret) credentials. but it is not working.
Somewhere I've read that replacing the api-key with the token would works, but no luck.
async function run2(){
const token = "<the-token>";
const deploymentName = "<the-deployment-name>";
const customUrl = "https://<resource-name>.openai.azure.com"

const client = new OpenAIClient(
    customUrl,
    new AzureKeyCredential(token)
);
const response = await client.getChatCompletions(
    deploymentName,
    [{role: "user", content: "How are you?"}]
);

console.log(response.choices![0]!.message!.content); }

Has anyone tried this before?

The AzureKeyCredential class is used for API key authentication only. You can indeed use a service principal to authenticate. You need to ensure you have registered an app and assigned the principal the "Cognitive Services User" role in your Azure OpenAI resource.
Using the Azure SDKs for Node.js and Entra ID, you have a couple of options.
Both of the below use the Azure Identity Library.
npm install @azure/identity

Use ClientSecretCredential

You can specify your Client ID, Client Secret, and Tenant ID in code, or load it from configuration or KeyVault. Here's an example:
import { ClientSecretCredential } from "@azure/identity";

async function run2(){
const credential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    "<YOUR_TENANT_ID>",
    "<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>",
    "<YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET>"
  );
const deploymentName = "<the-deployment-name>";
const customUrl = "https://<resource-name>.openai.azure.com"

const client = new OpenAIClient(
    customUrl,
    credential
);
const response = await client.getChatCompletions(
    deploymentName,
    [{role: "user", content: "How are you?"}]
);

console.log(response.choices![0]!.message!.content); }


Use AzureDefaultCredential

If you configured your App Service to use System Managed Identity, or User-defined Managed Identity then you can use this class. This will obtain a token from Entra automatically.
import { DefaultAzureCredential } from "@azure/identity";

async function run2(){
const deploymentName = "<the-deployment-name>";
const customUrl = "https://<resource-name>.openai.azure.com"

const client = new OpenAIClient(
    customUrl,
    new DefaultAzureCredential()
);
const response = await client.getChatCompletions(
    deploymentName,
    [{role: "user", content: "How are you?"}]
);

console.log(response.choices![0]!.message!.content); }

You do also have the option to use EnvironmentCredential, whereby you would set the appropriate environment variables for your app:

AZURE_TENANT_ID
AZURE_CLIENT_ID
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET


it is not what the question asks.

@Loebre the term OAuth 2.0 client is ambiguous when you don't include code to show how you got the token to begin with. MSAL acts as a OAuth 2.0 client, because it interacts with the authorization server. What you meant is OAuth 2.0 user, or application. The code you included leaves readers wondering where you got the token from, and naturally one can assume you used an OAuth client earlier in code to obtain the token - in which case, you could use the out-of-the-box token acquisition of the MSAL TokenCredential types. Pleass see my other answer.

The Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) doesn't provide a method to construct a TokenCredential using the token string, and OpenAIClient can only be passed types of this base type.
You'll need to create a custom token credential which extends TokenCredential. However, using this method, you will forfeit the built-in token lifecycle management mechanisms provided by the other TokenCredential types.
const { TokenCredential } = require('@azure/identity');

// Custom credential that uses an existing token string
class CustomTokenCredential extends TokenCredential {
  constructor(token) {
    super();
    this.token = token;
    this.expiresOnTimestamp = Date.now() + 3600 * 1000; // Set an expiry time, e.g., 1 hour from now
  }

  // Implement the getToken method
  async getToken(scopes, options) {
    return {
      token: this.token,
      expiresOnTimestamp: this.expiresOnTimestamp
    };
  }
}

// Usage example
async function main() {
  const token = 'your-existing-access-token'; // Replace with your token
  const credential = new CustomTokenCredential(token);

